# Axis of an object change direction with camera

Tags: transforms

I'm new to Blender and recently on my first creation. However, I encountered a  problem - the axis of an object flips (changes its direction) as I move the camera around the object. For example, whenever you start a new design, you will only be able to move the cube in six directions - up, down, left, right, back, forward. In my case, the directions of arrows will change. Is there any way to return the setting back to normal so that the axis won't flip?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! First thing I would check is the transformation orientation of the gizmo. What is it set on? Probably a screenshot of your screen would help in understanding your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure but I think I know how to fix it. Change the objects  transformation orientation from view to local/global.
First you need to select the object and then there should be an option at the bottom toolbar

[image]

Choose global or local, I am not sure which one you want but global is probably what you are asking for. The difference between local and global is that if you rotate the object in local the arrows would also rotate, while in global the arrows would always point in the same direction. Hope this help

*Note:* I assumed that by camera you meant view as there is a camera object in blender.

Comment: @alexander aganfonov  No problem